# Credit card hardware and API for WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7, credit-card

Is there a hardware credit card swipe, like square up, for Windows phone 7 that also includes an API to get the credit card data?

Answer (score 0):

A quick google search reveals this http://www.wpcentral.com/accumulus-develops-credit-card-payment-application-wp7

Other than that, no. WP7 is too small a market but square may do this at some point.